# protocolbuffer de-serialization without the class name in Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a serialized proto in a file(sample.dat). I was provided with the jar file which contains a lot of proto compiled files which are again compiled into .class files. I don't know the type or class of the proto in the sample.dat. How can I de-serialize it? Is there any generic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many proto descriptor types are we talking about in the jar file? Basically: can you look at each descriptor type and see if it works, or looks about right?

Basically, unless you're using the `Any` feature, protobuf data makes no mention of what any object's type is - you ideally just need to know. It is, however, quite easy to parse the raw format to look at what you're getting; you can do this with the `protoc` tool using the `--decode_raw` option, or online via tools like https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode. Either of this will show you *what it can* about your data, hopefully allowing you to figure out which type it looks like, based on comparing the structure you see to one of:

- the `message` definitions in a `.proto` file
- the generated types in source code
- the generated types in a library

Note: binary protobuf data does not include member names - just field numbers. If you can see the generated source, or attribute metadata, or *decompile* a compiled library to look at what the serialize/deserialize code looks like, you can *manually* map names to numbers by inspection - to figure out whether a type looks likely.

Note: if the java code contains descriptor binary for the types, the compiled descriptor data can *also* be decoded - each should represent a `DescriptorProto` from `descriptor.proto`. This won't help tell you what the root type is, but might help you understand each type, since it provides full access to the metadata.